# Can 'this' be passed into ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay()?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, polling

I'm looking at using the `java.util.concurrent` package for a simple polling class. Am a bit perplexed by the range of classes, interfaces and methods available for doing this so would appreciate some guidance. Here are my thoughts so far:

The first decision to make is how to instantiate the class for managing a schedule. There are a few possible options, e.g:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor =
    new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize)
```

...or...

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

...or...

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(corePoolSize);
```

Am leaning towards the last one but wondering what a sensible corePoolSize would be - perhaps 1 to keep things simple?

***EDIT:**  In the end I found most benefit in using the top method (i.e. directly instantiate [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)). [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) provides [`getActiveCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount()) for obtaining the number of active threads. This allowed me to implement a `pause()` method that waits until the pause has actually taken effect - see [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26250/discussion-between-assylias-and-steve-chambers).*

The next decision is whether to call [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable%2C%20long%2C%20long%2C%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable%2C%20long%2C%20long%2C%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). Am leaning towards `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` since the polling regularity isn't all that important and I don't like the idea of multiple polls occurring in quick succession after a bottleneck.

But here's the question: Would it be OK/advisable to use a single class that both starts the polling and represents the thread? E.g:

```
public class Poller extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }

    public void startPolling() {
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

The main part I'm not sure about here is the first `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` parameter: Will a new instance of this class be instantiated for each execution? Otherwise it surely wouldn't work since run() can't be called on the same Thread instance twice?

Comment: `Poller` should not extend `Thread` but only implement `Runnable`! - No new instances of the passed `Runnable` are created. The `run()` method is just called multiple times.

Comment: One does not submit `Thread` to the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: The whole point of the `Executors` is to provide a *pool* of threads to perform tasks concurrently. If, as in your example, you only want a single thread to regularly do some polling you would usually start/manage that single thread on your own, like  `Thread myThread = new Thread( myPoller );  myThread.start();`.

Comment: These are good comments and it makes more sense already. I'm used to extending Thread rather than implementing Runnable since this is normally the recommended way. So if I use Runnable instead then it seems the same instance would get reused for each execution? Wish the Oracle documentation mentioned this!

Comment: Imagine if this weren't so. How would/should the `ExecutorService` create a new instance of your object for the next execution? - It wouldn't be able to at all.

Comment: Hmmmm true - or at least only by using reflection - guess that's a bit far fetched!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have commented, all you need to change is Thread to Runnable. You might want to add some safe guard so that there is not multiple tasks being run.

```
public class Poller implements Runnable {
    final ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Future future = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }

    public void startPolling() {
        if (future != null && !future.isDone()) {
           future.cancel(true); // stop before restarting
           // or
           return; // already running
        }
        future = exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

BTW: If you have Java 5.0, the `run()` method does not have the `@Override`. For Java 6+, you should have the @Override.

> Will a new instance of this class be instantiated for each execution?

A new instances is created when you use the `new` operator.

> Otherwise it surely wouldn't work run() surely can't be called on the same Thread instance twice?

It can work because the use of Thread in your code is confusing as the thread you create is not used.  It just needs to be `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like good sensible code. Wish there was a way of sharing the answer as you and Hanno have both provided valuable input.

Comment: In that case, I would give it to the one with the least rep. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The single-threaded approach could use a `Poller` implementation like this:

```
public class Poller implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while ( mayContinue ) {
            poll();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Hanno. This seems a lot simpler - had considered doing something like this but then went on StackOverflow and got steered towards `java.concurrency` - but maybe that's over-thinking it given it's fairly small scale. The only thing is I'm integrating with an existing product and don't know much about how it uses threads - so perhaps java.concurrency could protect against potential issues and future-proof... Am in two minds now!

Comment: `mayContinue` must be volatile and Thread.sleep throws an InterruptedException which must be caught.

Comment: So which method would you suggest Peter? Am guessing ScheduledExecutorService must be there for a reason and protects against all the usual threading issues...

Comment: If I may, the `ExecutorService`s are there to allow *efficient* concurrent execution of *multiple* (usually short) tasks. A single `Executor` can for example use a single thread to process loads and loads of tasks without ever creating another thread except the first one. An `Executor` can also use a *pool* of multiple threads to process its tasks, again re-using threads instead of creating new ones over and over again. The `ScheduledExecutorService` is basically the same with the additional option to automatically delay or repeat the given tasks instead of processing them once and a.s.a.p..